# matplotlib's 'tab20' color repeats color after 10

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am plotting the distribution of a variable say a RMSF from multiple files into one histogram, such that each file belongs to a cluster. I have 25 clusters at the moment. The goal is to plot a single histograms for all clusters, coloring the bars by their clusters. I have a working code but even after using a color palette such as tab20 of matplotlib, I see that the colors repeat themselves after 10. My goal is to assign a distinct color to each cluster. At the moment I have 25, but I might have even more later. Following is my code:

```
import glob
from matplotlib import figure
import matplotlib.pypot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as mplcm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import os
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


filelist = glob.glob('alkenes_testrg_cluster*.csv')
filename = [((i.split('alkenes_testrg_')[1]).split('.')[0]).split('_')[0] for i in filelist]


cm = plt.get_cmap('tab20',25)
NUM_COLORS=25

sns.set(color_codes=True)
sns.set(rc={"xtick.bottom" : True, "ytick.left" : True})
sns.set_style('darkgrid')

#cNorm  = colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=NUM_COLORS-1)
#scalarMap = mplcm.ScalarMappable(norm=cNorm, cmap=cm)
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))


ax.set_prop_cycle('color', [cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS) for i in range(NUM_COLORS)])
for i,filen in enumerate(filelist):

  ### Read .csv file and append to list
  df = pd.read_csv(filen)
  bins=np.arange(df.RMSF_TOTAL.min(), df.RMSF_TOTAL.max(),0.005)
  if len(df.RMSF_TOTAL) > 5:
    
   plt.hist(df.RMSF_TOTAL,bins=bins,label=filename[i],alpha=0.9,rwidth=1)
    #print('cluster'+str(i+1),filen)

### Generate the plot
sns.set(color_codes=True)
plt.xlabel("RMSF", fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("Count", fontsize=20)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
plt.xticks(fontsize=20)
plt.yticks(fontsize=20)
plt.title('Raregas RMSF Distribution of'+'\n Parameter Based Clusters',fontsize=25)
ax.legend(fontsize=20, bbox_to_anchor=(1.0, 1.0),ncol=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: `tab20` has 20 colors.  Note that more than about 12 different colors are very hard to identify and distinguish visually.  If you have more than 10 types of areas, you might also need something such as hatching. Even then, you make it very hard for a viewer to identify each area.

Comment: Thanks @JohanC. Hatching is good idea! Although, my question was - when tab20 does have 20 colors, why do I see them repeating after 10?

Comment: `tab20`'s colors don't repeat after 10, but after 20.  The code is extremely messy.  Try to create a minimal reproducible example, without external input.  If you do `plt.get_cmap('tab20',25)`, you get a colormap with some colors repeated.  If you then sample  these in an odd way via `[cm(1.*i/NUM_COLORS) for i in range(NUM_COLORS)]` you again get some extra repeats.  Your code has a wrong indentation, making it hard to guess until where the `for` loop goes.  Plotting histograms on top of each other doesn't show the 20 colors well.  Having a gray background makes the colors harder to see.

Comment: You can set `ax.set_prop_cycle('color', plt.cm.tab20.colors)` to have the 20 colors repeating one-by-one.  But this doesn't mean you'll get 20 easily distinguishable colors.